# With open getting exception "must be str not tuple" even after conversion

Tags: python-3.x

So I have some jpg files that need to be resized. When I check each file in the for loop it says that it's a class <'str'> but when I do with open(jpg, 'rb') it's throwing me Exception "must be str, not tuple". Here is my code. The comments are there to help explain what each output gives you with print.

```
def send_files(self, con, agenciesid):
    successes = []
    errors = []
    l = []
    files = []
    files = copyfile.listdir(G.global_settings[(agenciesid, "afis_export_connection_string")])
    combine = ['/'.join(mugshot.values()) for mugshot in self.mugshots]

    for file in files:
        # file = # first file is IN202100005.txt, second file is IN202100005_F.jpg
        #type(file))= <class 'str'>
        extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
        print("extension is: ", extension) #('IN202100005_R', '.jpg')
        src = copyfile._parse_url(copyfile.join(G.global_settings[(agenciesid, "afis_export_connection_string")], file))
        # src= {'scheme': 'ftp', 'username': 'l', 'password': 'l', 'hostname': 'zt-dev', 'path': '/export/IN202100005_R.jpg'}
        if file.endswith("jpg"):
            jpg = str(file)
            print("if file endswith jpg ran")
            try:
                tmp_path = tempfile.mkstemp(extension, "afis-")
                print("tmp_path is: ", tmp_path)

                dest = copyfile._parse_url(tmp_path)
                print("dest is: ", dest)
                # copyfile.copyfile(src, dest)
                print("file before open is: ", jpg)
                with open(jpg, "rb") as mugshot1: #must be str, not tuple
                    print("type of mugshot is=: ", type(mugshot1))
                    im = Image.open(mugshot1)
                    print("im is=", im)
                    print("im type is=", type(im))
                    newsize = (480, 600)
                    im1 = im.resize(newsize)

                    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
                    im1.save(temp, format="JPEG")
                    temp.seek(0)
                    # copyfile.copyfile(im1, self.afis_export_connection_string)

                    copyfile.copyfile(src, dest)
                    temp.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print("exception is ", e)`enter code here`
```

Even after using str() on the file it is still giving me same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you [edit] to also post the *exact* error from the Traceback? There might be more information there. Also, [edit] to post the output of `print("file before open is: ", jpg)`. What is `jpg` at that point and what is `type(jpg)`?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate that exact error message, even when intentionally passing a tuple to `open()`.  Please always post the full traceback message.  (I suspect that you've overridden `open()` with another function.)

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming from tmp_path. My mistake of not having it outside the try since it will just throw my except error when Exception occurred.